# jQuery Dialog not working for me ..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to use jQuery dialogs, but they don't seem to load :(

HTML:

```
<p><a href="javascript:void(null);" onclick="showDialog()">Open</a></p>

<div id="dialog-modal" title="Basic modal dialog" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function showDialog()
{
    alert('Alert not showing');
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog(
    {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        open: function(event, ui)
        {
            var textarea = $('<textarea style="height: 276px;">');
            $(textarea).redactor({
                focus: true,
                autoresize: false,
                initCallback: function()
                {
                    this.set('<p>Lorem...</p>');
                }
            });
        }
     });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GsFSc/

Another example:

http://jsfiddle.net/khSxK/

What's the problem here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to include `jQuery UI` for dialog to work. In JSfiddle you have to include your `functions` in `head`. But better yet use jQuery's `click()`.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/khSxK/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Your version of jQuery is too low and you need to add jQuery UI for dialog to work, and i'd suggest not to use inline scripting. Use on() like this.

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
showDialog();
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/GsFSc/3/)

Answer (score 0):

1. you need jQuery UI along with up to date legacy jQuery
2. better use the `.click(...)` from jQuery : http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/Kat7G/

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><a href="javascript:showDialog();">Open</a></p>
```